# Integrated second derivative of a function of Brownian Motion is a Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am trying to prove: Let $g \in  C^{2}_{0}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $B_{t}$ be a Brownian Motion. Then, the following process is a martingale:
$$X_{t}=g(B_{t})-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}g''(B_{s})ds$$

My attempt: Let $(F_{t})$ be the canonical filtration. I need to show that
$$E[X_{t}-X_{s}|F_{s}] = E[g(B_{t})|F_{s}]-g(B_{s})-\frac{1}{2}E\bigg[\int_{s}^{t}g''(B_{r})dr\bigg|F_{s}\bigg]=0$$
My questions:

1. Is it true that $E[g(B_{t})|F_{s}]=E[g(B_{s})]$? How to prove it?
2. I can pull the conditional expectation into the integral using Riemann Sums. Using the same argument as above, it is then a normal expectation. Is that correct?
3. Then, I can use Fubini and get the integral $\int_{s}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g''(x)p(x,r)dxdr$ where $p$ is the normal density in $x$ with variance $r$ and mean $0$. I have integrated by parts twice to somehow get $g$ instead of $g''$, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using Ito's formula:
$$ g(B_t) = g(0)+\int_0^tg'(B_s) dB_s + \frac12 \int_0^t g''(B_s)ds. $$
Since $ \int_0^t E(g'(B_s))^2 ds< Kt <\infty$ and due to the definition of the Ito-integral $\int_0^t g'(B_s) dB_s$ is progressively measurable, $ \int_0^t g'(B_s)dB_s$ is a martingale. Now
$$ X_t = g(B_t) - \frac12 \int_0^t g''(B_s) ds = g(0) + \int_0^t g'(B_s)dB_s,$$
hence it is a martingale.

Without Ito's formula things are a bit more complicated.
$$ E[ g(B_t)| F_s] = E[ g(B_t-B_s + B_s) | F_s] = \big. E [ g(B_t-B_s +x)]\big|_{x=B_s} $$
due to the fact that $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $F_s$. Furthermore
$$ E[\int_s^t g''(B_r) dr| F_s] =\big. E[ \int_s^t g''( B_r- B_s +x)dr] \big|_{x= B_s} $$
Can you proceed from here?

The lemma. Let $X,Y$ be two random variables and let $F$ be a sigma-algebra, such that $X$ is $F$ measurable and $Y$ is independent of $F$. Let $g:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be a measurable function satisfying $E[|g(X,Y)|]<\infty$. Then
$$ E[g(X,Y)| F] = \big. E [ g(x,Y)] \big |_{x=X} \quad a.s.$$

Comment: Thanks! But I have this exercise from a script that hasn't introduced Ito at this point...

Comment: Oh, I see. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Still a few questions. What is the object $E[g(B_{t}-B_{s}+x]|_{x=B_{s}}$? Is it a random variable, maybe the expectation depending on the realization of $B_{s}(\omega)$? And if so, why exactly are we allowed to do this? I know that $g(B_{t}-B_{s})$ is independent of $F_{s}$ but how does this imply your equality?

Comment: It is a random variable, a function of $B_s$. We are allowed to do this because $B_t-B_s$ is independent of $F_s$. It is a very useful property of conditional expectation.

Comment: The solution is clear to me if I accept that this property really holds :D We get a double integral for any fixed $x$, use Fubini, integrate by parts twice and arrive at $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{s}^{t}g(y+x)\partial_{r}\phi(r-s,y)drdy$. Then use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mick ! Maybe could you just state a general version of this property you used? I will try to find a reference or prove it myself. It is more than the usual $E[g(X)|F]=E[g(X)]$ for $X$ independent of $F$ after all

Comment: Glad to help. Added the lemma to my answer.